# How to patch multiple properties in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have written a method that patches one field of a user, the code for that method is

```
    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
    public user PatchUser(user user)
    {
        user serverUser = db.users.Find(user.iduser);
        serverUser.profilepic=user.profilepic;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return serverUser;
    }
```

Right now i am using this code to patch by json , json is :

```
{
    iduser: 123,
    profilepic: "My profile link "
}
```

So how to modify this code to allow mutliple patches like i want to use the same url to patch other properties too. Like if i want to patch username the json should be:

```
{
    iduser: 123,
    username: "SomeUserName "
}
```

Comment: Its not duplicate, my scenario is wayyyyyyyyyyyy different

Comment: Do your keys need some greasing? m and y seem stuck?

Comment: I'm referring to your overuse of 'y' in wayy... and m in Hmm...

Comment: How to remove the duplicate stigma from my beautiful message

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm how is your scenario different?

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm, you'll need to edit your question to expose a difference to the duplicate.  Burning a flag on your question, so please act to correct it.  And a strategic tip:  avoid the emotive emphasis in your comments (just a tip)